# Finding length of side on right triangle on mercator projection

Tags: geometry, triangles, spherical-coordinates, spherical-geometry, spherical-trigonometry

[image: Triangle]
I have above triangle but actually it is on earth.

in general BC = AB *Sin y

but in my situation A, B and C are gps coordinates and I want to find true distance between B and C.

So far I know AD, AB, z and y angles.

I know the world radius which is 6,371 km or 6,371,000 m

I am using WGS-84 coordinates as well.

Point Coordinates:

A => Lat: 49.81666666666667 , Lon: -2.75

D => Lat: 50.493333333333332 , Lon: 0.98666666666666669

B => Lat: 50.028766666633331 , Lon: -1.75

AB = 40.729078462466845 Nautical Miles

y => 4.3753712076250508 degrees

Comment: Please, if possible change the color from yellow to something darker. Those lines are hardly visible

Comment: @samjoe , edited. hope it is better now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [spherical law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines#Spherical_case) you get

\begin{align*}
\frac{\sin\tfrac\pi2}{\sin\frac{AB}R}&=\frac{\sin y}{\sin\frac{BC}R}\\
\sin\frac{BC}R&=\sin\frac{AB}R\cdot\sin y\\
BC&=R\cdot\arcsin\left(\sin\frac{AB}R\cdot\sin y\right)
\end{align*}

This is assuming the earth is a sphere, not the more complicated [WGS-84 ellipsoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WGS_84).

It might be educating to see how the Euclidean law of sines gives rise to the formula you quoted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I need it in weird , more complicated WGS-84 Ellipsoid :) I am going to use it on a marine project and they use it for marine charts.

Comment: and what is R stands for? Earth Radius?

Comment: also other part I didn't understand AB and R are length. how can we use arcsin function for sin length * sin deg?

Comment: $R$ is earth's radius, yes. $\frac{AB}R$ is a ratio between an arc length and a radius, which is the common definition of the [radian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) angle measurement. So as long as you make sure to use radians not degrees as input to the $\sin$, feeding that ratio is fine. To do the same in WGS-84 you probably have insufficient information, as you don't seem to have the latitude of any of your points. If you do have it, please update your “so far I know …” list to really contain everything you know.

Comment: I just changed y angle to radian and works fine. Thanks!!!

Comment: I updated with coordinates and accepted the answer. Should I ask another question for WGS84 Ellipsoid answer or is it still good to go :)

Comment: I can't answer for WGS84. So you can hope for a more complete answer and accept that, but people might be disinclined to answer a question with an accepted answer, so a separate question might make sense. Please read things like https://stackoverflow.com/q/12800045/1468366 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/212867/20475 first, though. Both of them mention [Vincenty's formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty's_formulae) which seem like they should suite your needs. Might want to use an existing implementation in order to use tested code.